# TYPO3 6.2 output categories of a content element

Tags: typo3, categories, typo3-6.2.x

I use TypoScript to render content elements like that:

```
page.10 < styles.content.get
page.10.select.where = colPos=0
page.10.wrap = <section id="resources"><h1 class="section">Resources</h1><div class="accordion"> | </div></section>
page.10.renderObj.stdWrap.dataWrap = <div class="contentelement layout-{field:layout} type-{field:CType}"> | </div>
```

How can I output the categories associated with each content element? Ideally I would like to do it in the datawrap like {field:categories} but if that doesn't work I also wouldn't mind to append them in some separate HTML element.

I tried to implement a JOIN with the sys_category_record_mm table but didn't get anything working.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Here is my latest try:

```
page.10.renderObj.stdWrap.postCObject = CONTENT
page.10.renderObj.stdWrap.postCObject {
    wrap = <p class="categories">|</p>
    if.isTrue.field = categories
    table = tt_content
    select {
        uidInList.field = uid
        join = sys_category_record_mm ON tt_content.uid = sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign JOIN sys_category ON sys_category.uid = sys_category_record_mm.uid_local
        orderBy = sys_category.sorting
    }
    renderObj = TEXT
    renderObj {
        field = title
        wrap = |&nbsp;
    }
}
```

This only outputs an empty `<p class="categories"></p>` if the content element has categories assigned. But the categories don't get listed.

Comment: Have you had a look here: https://typo3.org/documentation/snippets/sd/471/ ?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't get it to work. The snippet has no effect? And I don't want the categories added to all headers globally but only in my page.10 section. How can I add it to my renderObj?

Answer (score 0):

```
page.10.renderObj.stdWrap.postCObject = CONTENT
page.10.renderObj.stdWrap.postCObject {
    wrap = <p class="categories">|</p>
    table = sys_category
    select {
        pidInList = 123  # Storage page/folder of your category records
        selectFields = sys_category.*
        join = sys_category_record_mm ON sys_category_record_mm.uid_local = sys_category.uid
        where.data = field:_LOCALIZED_UID // field:uid
        where.intval = 1
        where.wrap = sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign = |
        andWhere = sys_category_record_mm.tablenames = 'tt_content'
        orderBy = sys_category.sorting
        languageField = 0
    }
    renderObj = TEXT
    renderObj {
        #DEMO INCL TRANSLATED CAT NAMES:
        value = {field:uid}:{field:title} ---
        insertData = 1
        noTrimWrap = || | 
    }
}
```

Some details:

- `CONTENT.select` implements multiple inherent defaults, if you don't tell otherwise. One of them is to use the current page only. So if your categories are not stored within the current page (which is likely), you have to overwrite the default using `pidInList`.
- I don't know where you get your field:uid from. But if you use multiple languages you will have to provide the uid of the overlay record. This is done in the `where.data` clause. If you are calling this TS from a Fluid template, you will find the uid of the overlay record in `data._LOCALIZED_UID`. If you are in a single language system, you may stay with uid only.
- You must also filter for `tablenames = 'tt_content'`. Otherwise you might get back categories that are assigned to other tables (like `tx_news_domain_model_news` from EXT News records).